# Using librets(PInvoke) in worker role

Tags: azure, pinvoke, azure-worker-roles

I am trying to create a worker role to download data from RETS server using librets.net. librets.net is a wrapper on  a c++ library librets. I tried both 32 bit and 64 bit version and followed this articlebut no success. I am still receiving
**BadImageFormatException**

How can i solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`BadImageFormatExceptions` are almost **always** a 32 bit/64 bit incompatibility; If I were a betting man, I'd say you are binding the wrong version based on your `Platform` configuration in Visual Studio.

- Choosing "Any CPU" will result in an assembly that will be JITted into a 64 bit version when loaded into a 64 bit process and a 32 bit version when loaded into a 32 bit process
- Choosing "x86" will always result in a 32 bit assembly

I'd be willing to bet you've got:

- "Any CPU" selected
- A 64 bit computer
- A 32-bit only version of the C++ library

Try switching everything over to 32 bit first; `x86` for Platform, use the 32 bit version of the library, etc.

Comment: Another thing is http://www.crt.realtors.org/projects/rets/librets/downloads/ provide to type.This time i tried with Mingw64 and it works. other 64bit was showing the same error. whats the difference between these two types of build?

Comment: Without digging into the particulars (not familiar with the library myself), I'd be outright guessing...possibly due to how Mingw64 structures the output binaries?